# Rails - Better way to query conditions on join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am playing around with a bucket list and I have the following models:

```
BucketList > BucketListItem < Item
```

BucketListItem is the join table between the two.

When I'm displaying all of the items and allowing users to either add them to their own bucket list or mark them as complete, I need to know whether or not that user has the item on their bucket list, and also whether they have marked it as done or not. I've come up with a working solution but it feels like there should be a better way of doing it.

In the controller:

```
@user_items = current_user.bucket_list.items
@user_bucket_list_items = current_user.bucket_list.bucket_list_items

@completed_user_items = []
current_user.bucket_list.bucket_list_items.where(status: 1).each do |bucket_list_item| 
  @completed_user_items << bucket_list_item.item
end
```

In the partial that renders each of the items:

```
<% if @user_items.include?(item) %>
  <p>Added</p>
<% else %>
  <%= form_for(BucketListItem.new, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :item_id, value: item.id %>
    <%= f.submit "+ Add" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<% if @completed_user_items.include?(item) %>
  <p>Done</p>
<% elsif @user_items.include?(item) %>
    <%= form_for(@user_bucket_list_items.where(item_id: item.id).first, remote: true) do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :status, value: "done" %>
      <%= f.submit "Mark as Done" %>
    <% end %>
<% else %>
    <%= form_for(BucketListItem.new, remote: true) do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :item_id, value: item.id %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :status, value: "done" %>
      <%= f.submit "Mark as Done" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It's particularly the second `if` statement that feels a little convoluted to me. Am I missing an obvious easier way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: if a `User` `has_one :bucket_list`, then it should `has_many :items, through: :bucket_list`, and therefore `current_user.items.where(id: item.id).exists?` would be a much more efficient way to test this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well view wise there is not much scope of optimization, But you can optimize your queries in controller

```
#In Controller
@bucket_list = current_user.bucket_list
@user_items = @bucket_list.items
# More efficient way of getting item which are not yet completed
@completed_user_items = current_user.items.where(bucket_list_items: { status: 1 })


#In view
<% if @user_items.include?(item) %>
  <p>Added</p>
<% else %>
  <%= form_for(BucketListItem.new, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :item_id, value: item.id %>
    <%= f.submit "+ Add" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<% if @completed_user_items.include?(item) %>
  <p>Done</p>

#Here I have used @bucket_list
<% elsif @user_items.include?(item) %>
    <%= form_for(item.bucket_list_items.where(bucket_list: @bucket_list).first, remote: true) do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :status, value: "done" %>
      <%= f.submit "Mark as Done" %>
    <% end %>
<% else %>
    <%= form_for(BucketListItem.new, remote: true) do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :item_id, value: item.id %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :status, value: "done" %>
      <%= f.submit "Mark as Done" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Ah that's brilliant, thanks! I wasn't aware you could do what you did for `@completed_user_items`, is it basically the case that you can use relationship methods in activerecord queries?

Comment: Yes
When you are fetching `items` for `bucket_list` it will automatically fire a join query using `bucket_list_items` because of many to many association.
So `bucket_list_items ` would be available for Activerecord query, otherwise you have to first include that table in Activerecord query with the help of `joins or includes` method